# JS function broke after jQuery upgrade

Tags: javascript

I have a function that was drawing items on SVG and placed a background under the text label. After much needed upgrade to latest jQuery second half of the function (node.insert...) broke, throwing error: NS_ERROR_FAILURE

```
function highlighted_label(node, txt, padding)
{
    if( !padding )
        padding = { horizontal: 3, vertical: 2 };

    node.append("svg:text")
        .attr("dominant-baseline", "middle")
        // IE 9 doesn't support dominant-baseline, so shift the text manually
        // Opera dosen't seem to support even y/dy ...
        .attr("y", $ && $.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 10 ? 4 : 0)
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .text(typeof txt === "function" ? function(d, i) { return txt.call(this, d, i) } : txt)
    ;

    // we need to add highlight background after text was appended so we can get text dimensions,
    // but we also need to insert the background before text so it will be drawn under the text
    node.insert("svg:rect", "text")
        .attr("width", function(d) { return this.nextSibling.getBBox().width + 2 * padding.horizontal; })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return this.nextSibling.getBBox().height + 2 * padding.vertical; })
        .attr("x", function(d) { return this.nextSibling.getBBox().x - padding.horizontal; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return this.nextSibling.getBBox().y - padding.vertical; })
        .attr("rx", 2)
    ;
}
```

If I replace width, height, x and y with numeric values, it works, but clearly I need to have the values generated dynamically. I've tried changing nextSibling to nextNode and nextElementSibling but to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the output of `this.nextSibling` && `this.nextSibling.getBBox()`?

Comment: It supposed to create a rectangle based on the width of the text and place it below the text with padding and x/y coords.

Comment: OK but does it still return value? It seems that this part to `getBox()` might be causing the issue. Did you make sure it still is valid and works?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. console.log(this.nextSibling); produces "undefined"

Comment: I also tried removing .getBBox() but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: My best guess is if you return an int value instead of what is happening in the `function(d)` and it works then you have to look into `this.nextSibling.getBBox().x/y` and the `padding.horizontal/vertical`. e.g.: `function(d) { reutrn 5 }`